# How to use CNContactPickerViewController with objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, cncontact

Hi I'm new to iOS development. I want to pick a contact from default contacts app. For that i created an application that lets user to pick a contact from the iPhone default contacts app. For iOS 9+ version, I'm using the following snipped.

```
- (IBAction)btnAction:(id)sender {

    CNContactPickerViewController *contactPicker = [[CNContactPickerViewController alloc] init];

    contactPicker.delegate = self;
    contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = (NSArray *)CNContactGivenNameKey;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void) contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact{
    NSLog(@"Contact : %@",contact);
}

-(void)contactPickerDidCancel:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker {
    NSLog(@"Cancelled");
}
```

I also added CNContactPickerDelegate delegate in my uiviewcontroller. When i execute the above code, it opens the contacts app, But when Tap a contact the app becomes blank.

Thanks in advance and can anyone please share your knowledge to use CNContactPickerViewController in Objective-C.

Answer (score 7):

The issue is caused by this code:

```
contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = (NSArray *)CNContactGivenNameKey;
```

The [displayedPropertyKeys](https://developer.apple.com/reference/contactsui/cncontactpickerviewcontroller/1619203-displayedpropertykeys?language=objc) expects an `NSArray` which contains `NSString` values. In your code, you are trying to type cast an NSString to NSArray and set as the value of this property.

You need to change your code to:

```
contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = @[CNContactGivenNameKey];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
#pragma mark - CNContactPickerViewController Delegate method implementation
(void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContact:(CNContact *)contact
{
    NSMutableArray *contactNumberArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    selectedName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",contact.givenName];
    NSLog(@"%@",selectedName);
    NSString *tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"name : %@ %@ %@\n",contact.givenName, contact.familyName, contact.organizationName];
    //    // 1.  (Phone Numbers)
        tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@phoneNumbers : ",tempString];
       // NSArray*phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers;
        for (CNLabeledValue *phoneNumber in contact.phoneNumbers)
        {
          CNPhoneNumber *phone = phoneNumber.value;
            tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<%@>",tempString,phone.stringValue];
             [contactNumberArray addObject:phone];
            selectedPhNumber=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",phone.stringValue] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
             NSLog(@"%@",selectedPhNumber);
        }

         //2.  (Emails)
        tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n Email : ",tempString];
        for (CNLabeledValue *email in contact.emailAddresses)
        {
            selectedEmail=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", email.value];
            tempString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@<%@>",tempString,email.value];
               [contactNumberArray addObject:email];
             NSLog(@"%@",selectedEmail);
        }
 [self sendRefferelDetailsToServer];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)contactPicker:(CNContactPickerViewController *)picker didSelectContacts:(NSArray<CNContact *> *)contacts{

    NSLog(@" %@",contacts);

    CNContact *contact=[contacts objectAtIndex:0];

    NSLog(@"name = %@",contact.givenName);


}
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Sp1G.png use above code to for fetch given name from multiple selections,

Answer (score -1):

comment the following line and try again.

```
//contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = (NSArray *)CNContactGivenNameKey;
```